# mockkStatic and mockkObject doesn't mock companion objects in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, mockk

I have a very simple class:

```
class TestClass {

    companion object {
        fun sampleFunc(value: Int): Int {
            return value + 5
        }
    }
}
```

and a very simple test:

```
@Test
fun `test class`() {
    mockkObject(TestClass::class)
    every {
        TestClass.sampleFunc(any())
    } returns 11

    assertThat(TestClass.sampleFunc(5)).isEqualTo(11)
}
```

Stack trace:

```
Failed matching mocking signature for

left matchers: [any()]
io.mockk.MockKException: Failed matching mocking signature for

left matchers: [any()]
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.SignatureMatcherDetector.detect(SignatureMatcherDetector.kt:99)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.RecordingState.signMatchers(RecordingState.kt:39)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.RecordingState.round(RecordingState.kt:31)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.CommonCallRecorder.round(CommonCallRecorder.kt:50)
    at io.mockk.impl.eval.RecordedBlockEvaluator.record(RecordedBlockEvaluator.kt:59)
    at io.mockk.impl.eval.EveryBlockEvaluator.every(EveryBlockEvaluator.kt:30)
    at io.mockk.MockKDsl.internalEvery(API.kt:92)
    at io.mockk.MockKKt.every(MockK.kt:104)
```

MockK version: 1.9.3
OS: mac
Kotlin version: 1.5.21
JDK version: 11
JUnit version: 4.12

Any idea?  I also tried mockkStatic with the same results.

Comment: I am not quite sure but shouldn't you have used a regular class mocking here like `val testClass = mockkClass(TestClass::class)` and then `every { testClass.something(any()) } returns 11`

Comment: Actually I tried that @nuhkoca and it would not compile.  It is a static class.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to this answer: https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/136#issuecomment-419879755

```
@Test
fun `test class`() {
    mockkObject(TestClass.Companion)
    every {
        TestClass.sampleFunc(any())
    } returns 11

    assertThat(TestClass.sampleFunc(5)).isEqualTo(11)
}
```

Does the trick, and it does.

Comment: This answer just saved me from two days of exhausting work. Thanks